# Grakn, create entity composed by entity?

Tags: graph, entity, artificial-intelligence, vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

I'm very new on GRAKN.AI and I'm wondering if in a GRAKN's graph I can create an "entity" composed by an "enitity". I know I can do the following code:

```
table sub entity
   has book;

book sub resources datatype string;
```

**But can I relate the "book" as an entity to the "table" ??**

**I need to have "book" as a complex concept and not as a simple resource.**

Thanks,

Davide.

Comment: Could you please specify what you mean by "having book as a complex concept"? What is it that you are trying to achieve? Do you want book to be returned as a type of table or do you want book to be a part of the table or do you want tables and books to be in some other kind of relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution is to go through a relationship which allows you to define things more explicitly. For example,

To define a relationship you start by defining roles which provide context for how things relate to each other. For example:

```
insert
    thing-on-top-of-table sub role;
    table-with-thing-on-top sub role;
```

You then say how these roles link to the relationship and to the entities:

```
insert    
    sits-on sub relation 
        relates thing-on-top-of-table
        relates table-with-thing-on-top;
    table plays table-with-thing-on-top;
    book plays thing-on-top-of-table;
```

The above is pretty much the schema of your simple knowledge base.

Now we can add some data. Let's say some book is on top of some table:

```
insert 
    $book isa book;
    $table isa table;
    (thing-on-top-of-table: $book, table-with-thing-on-top: $table) isa sits-on
```

Naturally you can expand things from here. For example you can give your book a title via a resource.

**Side Note: Resources Vs Entities**

The basic rule of thumb for relating something as a resource or as another entity depends on how much information you want to express in the model as well as if something can be defined by a data literal (e.g. String, Int, Long, etc . . . ).

For example a book is an entity because it is made up of multiple resources which help identify the book. I.e. the title, isbn, etc. . . those resources on the other hand are simple data values. A title is nothing but a string so there is no reason to make the title an entity, that should be fine as just a resource.

Comment: Nice way to name the relations. Way better than `belongs`

Answer (score 3):

You couold model two entites `book`and `table` and have a relation that you could call something like `belongs` and add the roles you need e.g. `book-role` and `table-role`

If the concepts are hierarchically related you can use inheritance.

```
table sub entity
  has some property

book sub table
  has additional property
```

Inheritance is usefull for classification you can easily understand that two sub entities are related and both can be retrieved by querying the parent.

```
match $t isa table;
```

would return the books as they are children entities of table.